# How to get all rows from a WPF DataGrid with scroll

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have some code that will convert data from a DataGrid into a CSV file. This works well but I need to convert all the rows and not just the rows that appears on the screen currently (Itemsource) is there a way to get all the rows?

```
// create one file gridview.csv in writing mode using streamwriter
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\gridview.csv");
            // now add the gridview header in csv file suffix with "," delimeter except last one
            for (int i = 0; i < dgProductList.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
               sw.Write(dgProductList.Columns[i].Header);
               if (i != dgProductList.Columns.Count)
               {
                  sw.Write(",");
               }
            }
            // add new line
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);


            // iterate through all the rows within the gridview
            foreach (DataGridRow dr in Utilities.GetDataGridRows(dgProductList))
            {
               // iterate through all colums of specific row
               for (int i = 0; i < dgProductList.Columns.Count; i++)
               {
                  // write particular cell to csv file
                  DataGridCell cell = Utilities.GetCell(dgProductList,dr, i);
                  TextBlock tb = cell.Content as TextBlock;

                  sw.Write(tb.Text);
                  if (i != dgProductList.Columns.Count)
                  {
                     sw.Write(",");
                  }
               }
               // write new line
               sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            }
            // flush from the buffers.
            sw.Flush();
            // closes the file
            sw.Close();


 public static IEnumerable<DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(DataGrid grid)
      {

         var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
         if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
         foreach (var item in itemsSource)
         {
            var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
            if (null != row) yield return row;
         }
      }
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post the code for Utilities.GetDataGridRows

Comment: We generally wouldn't do anything like that in WPF. Instead we data bind a collection of data to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` and then when we need to access the data, we just access the data bound collection directly. Calling `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex` with items that haven't been generated will return `null` as you are aware, so you should change your code to work with data elements rather than UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

Could well be a virtualization problem.  Try setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` on your datagrid properties.